# SQL Server 2008 get file from ftp

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, ftp, ssis, getfiles

We used SQL Server 2005 with the queries shown and `bat` file, but after passing to SQL Server 2008 64-bit we get some errors. When I searched it, people recommend to use **SSIS**, so I did but I can't get file with dynamic file name (like Test_20130426.xls).

Step 1:

```
Declare @myComm varchar(1000)
Declare @folderName varchar(1000)

SET @folderName = 'C:\Test\' 
SET @myComm = @folderName +'Transfer.bat'

Exec MASTER..xp_cmdShell @myComm
```

Step 2(Transfer.bat):

```
ftp -i -s:C:\Test\FTPGetCommand.bat
pause
```

Step 3(FTPGetCommand.bat):

```
open ip addres of ftp
user
pass
CD /Test/
lcd C:\Test\received_file
mget *.*
close
quit
```

Step 4:

```
Declare @vSql varchar(5000)
Declare @vDate varchar(1000)

SET @vTarih=CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),112)

SET @vSql='insert into dbo.test_table SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'',  
   ''Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Test\received_file\Sales_'+@vDate+'.xls'', FORMAT$)'

print @vSql
exec (@vSql)
```

Comment: Right, *We get some errors* about says it all...

Comment: step 1's error; output NULL
C:\Windows\system32>ftp -i -s:C:\Test\FTPGetCommand.bat 
Error opening script file C:\Test\FTPGetCommand.bat.

Comment: step 4's error;Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.

Comment: Error for step one is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: cmd shell was enabled I also checked with the query; SELECT CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(value, value_in_use)) AS config_value
FROM  sys.configurations
WHERE  name = 'xp_cmdshell' ;

Comment: Since your original problem seemed to be setting a filename dynamically in the SSIS FTP task, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571085/ssis-dynamic-file-name-for-ftp-component). Personally I would write a small script in PowerShell, Python or some other language to do this, instead of trying to call batch files from TSQL.